# How do I conditionally validate a 1-1 model relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, relationship

I have a model, Person, that requires a schedule if it's type is "scheduled". In it's controller (which inherits from `InheritedResources::Base`):

```
def create
  super do
    @person.schedule = Schedule.create params[:schedule] if @person.scheduled?
  end
end
```

The thing is, I want to validate that all People of type "scheduled" have a schedule. Something like this:

```
validates :schedule, :presence => true, :if => :scheduled?
```

in the Person model. But because a schedule `belongs_to` a Person, it needs the person to be created prior to being created itself (so the person will have an ID). So with this in my controller, the person validation fails, since the schedule needs to be created later.

Is there something in Rails that I don't know about, which will enable me to perform these validations? If I used `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, will that allow these validations to pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just don't create it beforehand?

```
@person.schedule = Schedule.new params[:schedule] if @person.scheduled?
```

So @person and assigned Schedule shall be saved **at the same time** (transaction).

I think this is the only correct way.

---

**UPDATED** (due to super :create conception):

## super action

```
def create(&block)
  ...
  yield @person if block_given?
  @person.save # line where @person get saved
end
```

## inherited action

```
def create
  super do |person|
    person.schedule = Schedule.new params[:schedule] if person.scheduled?
  end
end
```

Comment: The Person object gets created in the call to `super`, so when there is no schedule at that point, the validation will fail at that line. But if I build the schedule object before the key is created, the schedule won't have the correct person reference (since the person wasn't created yet, it has no ID).

Comment: If person object created in the super call, you'd better to change action logic. "Sheduled?" checking has to take place before the person is saved. You can show us full code of this action and super action to make it more clear.